# htaccess allow only numbers after a certain point with https

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i attached my current htaccess file below, it currently makes all my urls www with trailing slash at the end and if it is on and only on /prepaid/ it will be https.

i am tring to extend this functionality, where i can also accept requests from /prepaid/refill/*a 10 digit phone number* and have it be https as well

i started by adding this line at the bottom, but how would i extend the https part to allow from this path as well?

```
  RewriteRule  ^prepaid/refill/([0-9]+)/?$        index.php?p=prepaid&phone=$1     [L]
```

the current code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.                      [NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/?$     https://www.domain.com/prepaid/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^prepaid/(.+)   http://www.domain.com/prepaid/$1    [R=301,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^prepaid/?$                 index.php?p=prepaid                 [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/h2o-wireless/?$        index.php?p=prepaid&s=h2o           [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/net10-wireless/?$      index.php?p=prepaid&s=net10         [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/page-plus-cellular/?$  index.php?p=prepaid&s=pageplus      [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/red-pocket-mobile/?$   index.php?p=prepaid&s=redpocket     [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/simple-mobile/?$       index.php?p=prepaid&s=simplemobile  [L]
```

Comment: So you want to force HTTPS on `prepaid/refill/<number>` in addition to forcing HTTPS on `prepaid/` while forcing non-https on everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your full .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# force HTTPS for /prepaid/ OR /prepaid/refill/([0-9]+)/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteRule ^prepaid(/refill/[0-9]+)?/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

# force HTTP for everything else
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^prepaid/(?!refill/[0-9]+).+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

# internal rewrites
RewriteRule ^prepaid/?$                     index.php?p=prepaid                 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/h2o-wireless/?$        index.php?p=prepaid&s=h2o           [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/net10-wireless/?$      index.php?p=prepaid&s=net10         [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/page-plus-cellular/?$  index.php?p=prepaid&s=pageplus      [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/red-pocket-mobile/?$   index.php?p=prepaid&s=redpocket     [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/simple-mobile/?$       index.php?p=prepaid&s=simplemobile  [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/refill/([0-9]+)/?$     index.php?p=prepaid&phone=$1        [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: worked just about flawlessly, only thing is when the request is on a http url, there is an extra slash added after .com so im getting http://domain.com//prepaid/simple-mobile/

Comment: Hmm ok can you try commenting out `force trailing slash` rule just for testing and test in a new browser.

Comment: it is still doing the same thing

Comment: yes, it looks like your code adds a trailing slash to each block, this includes a slash after the .com. my php setup for site links var already has a trailing slash in the url "http://www.domain.com/" so it ends up being double, i just removed the slash from my var and it works now

Answer (score 0):

to use https need write some ike this 
with regular expressions, you must be caution and be:
\d+ - its only numberic characters

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule  ^prepaid/refill/(\d+)/?$        index.php?p=prepaid&phone=$1     [L]
```